# Totally Disable Junk Mail in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, spam-prevention

I have a problem with junk mail filtering in Thunderbird and I just want to turn it off completely; however as far as I can see it's not actually enabled anywhere; and further to that I went into my server and added to the whitelist one email address in particular (which is constantly being marked as junk in Thunderbird). I did this just to rule out the mail server as a possible culprit, but I didn't think it was anyway because a) I think it is currently set to delete junk, and b) I think that when mail servers don't just delete the junk they mark it with SPAM or something in the subject.

So the things that I have done to turn off junk mail are the following:

1. Account settings > Junk settings > unticked "turn off adaptive junk mail ... " ( this I would have thought would have done the trick alone but not so) ... I also did this under local folders just in case that was what was doing it.
2. Checked "Do not mark as junk mail if the sender is in .." ticked all .... and the sender is in all too. I know this shouldn't matter in light of 1 but I did it anyway.
3. Checked for a message filter under tools>>message filters. Only my own ones are there.
4. Tools>options>>advanced>>junk unticked everything (and also clicked "reset training data" in case that was it)

I can't think of anything else but I have read some posts on the internet where others are having a similar problem. I have been a happy user of Thunderbird for about 5 years now but unfortunately if I can't fix this I'll have to switch to something else, who knows what, as it's actually unreliable as it is.

Comment: Are you saying that the emails are still moved to the Junk folder?  Do they have the "junk" flag on when they get there?

Comment: Yes they are still moved to the junk folder; and they have a junk flag and a button for me to press "not junk"

Comment: I can't see how that is possible!  I would be inclined to think your profile has become corrupted somehow, it certainly isn't normal behaviour, and isn't something I have seen in all the mess-ups I have experienced with Thunderbird.  Could you create a new profile for testing and see if it does the same thing?

Comment: Thanks Paul. I was thinking possibly something might have gone askew somewhere - I thought it might have something to do with the program either - so I was thinking i might just reinstall it again, as I am using Imap - I dont think it will be a big chore.

Comment: Sure but reinstalling thunderbird will not make any difference to a corrupt profile.

Comment: I meant that I would setup the profile again from scratch in the process; I just thought it would be easier than testing to see if the profile was corrupt and then fixing it, seing as there's nothing really to it, just the email accounts, all the folder structure is on the server ... am I wrong, maybe I am ?

Comment: Great - then skip the step of re-installing Thunderbird, it won't do anything.  You can simply rename your profile folder and it will create a new one next time you start thunderbird.

Comment: Thanks for that rename tip - but I just thought that the installation itself could be corrupt either/instead.

Comment: It is certainly possible, but the behaviour you are describing (and with TB almost any issue) is most likely down the the profile.  It will just save you a bit of time.

Comment: Thanks, then I might just give that a shot. Can I ask if i rename the profile back afterwards will it pick up on it again ?

Comment: Yep it will.  You can also run them concurrently and choose at startup, if you take a look at profiles.ini

Comment: A word of warning: the task of creating another profile is not simple. I haven't found any way to export some settings and reimport them in the newer profile. Every setting (incl. message tags, extensions and their own configuration) ever changed has to be set again. The reconfiguration became too overwhelming for me and I returned to the old default profile, resigned to live with this weird behavior of Thunderbird. I've noted no file gets changed on the disk as a result of my marking a message as non-junk. Once flagged, the message remains flagged.

Answer (score 2):

This video explains all... it's under Tools -> Account Settings.  Each individual accoutn has its own junk mail settings, so go in there and uncheck the box:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7KrnFVVYBY

Comment: Didn't the user say he'd done that? If the YouTube video actually addresses the problem, you shoud summarize here.

Comment: The profile seemed to be corrupt, I haven't had this problem since I created the new profile

Answer (score 1):

Create a new profile and reconfigure your mail settings.

*The answer from the OP @byronyasgur was left in a comment:*

> "The profile seemed to be corrupt, I haven't had this problem since I
>   created the new profile"